# Insert into RavenDB; Fastest way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, insert, nosql, ravendb

I want to import 100 million entries from a text file (each row is one csv-like entry) into a RavenDB database. What is the fastest way to do this?

Additional Notes:

I have not any indexes yet (I will create them after inserting the data). RavenDB is running in service mode on local machine with no security enhancements (yet; because I am still testing RavenDB). This test will run on 2 different machines, 1) 2 cores 4GB ram 2) 8 cores 12 GB ram.

I have done inserting a portion of this data (2 million entries) into RavenDB but it was not as fast as I would like. By using OpenAsyncSession and calling SaveChangesAsync for every 1024 records and again creating a new session by calling OpenAsyncSession and not waiting for return Task (returned by SaveChangesAsync) after 500`000 entries or so, I get an "Index out of range" exception that I can not root out. But if I wait for tasks to end (by creating them same as number of cores), process will succeed but not fast enough.

This code ran successfully:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\*\DATA.TXT", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line = null;
    IAsyncDocumentSession session = null;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var locCount = 0;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

        var loc = Parse(line);

        if (session == null) session = documentStore.OpenAsyncSession();

        session.Store(loc);
        locCount++;

        if (locCount % 1024 == 0 && session != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var t = session.SaveChangesAsync();
                tasks.Add(t);
                session = null;
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                // ... something ...
            }
        }

        if (tasks.Count >= NUMBER_OF_CORES)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.Clear();
        }
    }

    if (session != null)
    {
        if (tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.Clear();
        }
        session.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
        session = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't wait for completion, it will look fast of course. Because processing has not completed yet. This is not a valid benchmark.

Comment: A document database is not about "records". You probably want to see how that data can be modeled to fit in a document database. For examples of similar scenarios see http://ayende.com/blog/154401/ravendb-amp-freedb-an-optimization-opportunity and http://ayende.com/blog/156386/geo-location-amp-spatial-searches-with-ravendbndash-part-iindash-modeling

Comment: @synhershko I know - to some level - it's about documents and I have used word "record" here because at the time I have not a better word for it; "entry" maybe? "object"? "information"? I do not know...Thanks!

Comment: My point - you may very well require doing an insert of a lot less than you think. The fastest way would be to use a simple console application to do this in batches - the session API will do that for you if you'll call SaveChanges on every bunch of them. Most of time you'll find reading the data from your sources will take the majority of time.

Comment: @usr processing HAS been completed, RavenDB is ACID. Indexing may not have caught-up, but all the info is already available.

Comment: @synhershko I call SaveChangesAsync #number-of-core times and wait after that for all tasks to complete and then continue; that works. But if I pass that number of tasks and do not wait for them to complete, after some point it fails! Thanks!

Comment: @synhershko, the OP said he is starting the inserts asynchronously and not waiting for them to finish. Of course that is fast, but it's not real. Requests queue up and eventually fail.

Comment: @usr No; that's not the case. I said if I don't wait for them to complete; the process will fail (at about 500`000 entries).

Comment: @KavehShahbazian, your process if failing *because you don't wait*. You are starting too many parallel operations.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian I didn't notice that fact, usr is right. Don't do this the async way, it doesn't add anything. Writes in Raven return immediately anyway (minus the network traffic).

Comment: @synhershko Again no! usr did not read my note carefully. If I use async writes, IT_WILL_BE_FASTER AND WILL_COMPLETE IF AND ONLY IF I USE #NUMBER_OF_CORES TASKS (returned by calling SaveChangesAsync) AND WAIT FOR THAT #NUMBER_OF_CORES TASKS TO COMPLETE AND AGAIN CREATE ANOTHER #NUMBER_OF_CORES TASKS. That succeeded and is fast; but not fast enough.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian, you'd need to provide some code samples at this point in order to get help. I feel this conversation is not fruitful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kaveh,

There are a number of issues here.

1) RavenDB models *very rarely* map to CSV files. If you have a CSV file, you usually have tabular format, and that isn't a good format to port to RavenDB. You can probably get better results by getting good models.

2) You code, without the `if (tasks.Count >= NUMBER_OF_CORES)`, will generate as many tasks as possible (subject to the limit of reading lines from the file, which is *really* fast.
This will tend to generate thousands of concurrent tasks, and will overload the number of requests RavenDB can insert at once.

3) Use the standard session, use a batch size of 1,024 - 2,048. And just let it run.
RavenDB is really good in optimizing, and I expect that you'll see thousands of inserts per second easily.

But, again, you are probably modeling things wrong.